# First time user used Facebook App

Tags: facebook

How can I tell if its the user's first time that he/she is using my facebook application. I want to do some initialisations for the user but only for the first time.

Comment: One simple way is that I store a list of the users who has used my app and whenever someone uses my app, I check if they are listed. Is there  a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find anything better so I did what I preciously suggested: I store a list of user IDs (on a db) and check if the user has previously used my app. If its the user's first time, I perform the required initialisations and then add him/her to the list...

Answer (score 0):

If you have acces to a database for storing variables. It should be easy enough to make a variable called uservisitsount.

Then you just count the variable up one time when the user log into the app.
    uservisitsount++;

then you can have a piece of code like.
if(uservisitsount ==0)
{do something the first time}

regards christen

Answer (score 0):

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    // the user is logged in and has authenticated your
    // app, and response.authResponse supplies
    // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
    // request, and the time the access token 
    // and signed request each expire
    var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
    var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
  } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
    // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
    // but has not authenticated your app
  } else {
    // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
  }
 });
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus